# Firebase Storage: Is it possible to auto - delete old files?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I use firebase cloud storage to upload images.

The app I am working on allows users to send images to one another (a chat thing), so that one user uploads the photo and another one will download it and once it is downloaded it should be deleted from the storage.

**Example of what I am talking about**

User A sends a photo to User B by uploading it to firebase storage, then User B notices that User A send him an image and decides to download it, after User B downloaded the image it should be deleted from storage.

**My question**

What if User A sends too many images and User B never downloads any of these images. Then this means that I will end with useless images on storage taking space.

So in this case is there a way in firebase to auto delete a file after it has been uploaded after (n) amount of time (not client side)?

Comment: It seems like your looking for [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)

Comment: @AndréKool how do I do this with functions?

Comment: I have no idea. I posted that link so you can find that out yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I am still in the middle of doing this research, but it seems like you can use [life cycle rules](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to delete files based on the age of the file.

Here are a few examples listed in the intro of the doc.

> - Downgrade the storage class of objects older than 365 days to
>     Coldline Storage.
> - Delete objects created before January 1, 2013.
> - Keep only the 3 most recent versions of each object in a bucket with
>     versioning enabled

Comment: You can also use lifecycle to delete files X days after they were created. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: How i can did it?

Comment: I ended up building out database models for each file and delete the file when the database entry was deleted - using firebase/firestore's onDelete hook. This is flexible because you can query database models easily based on their properties and delete them.